# Clubbing Remote Processing Power

Tags: linux

I have few systems with following configurations.

```
Computer_Name Total_Processing_Power Used_Processing_Power Total_RAM Used_RAM
Computer1       2GHz                  1.2Ghz                2GB      1.4GB
Computer2       2GHz                  1.0Ghz                2GB      1.1GB
Computer3       2GHz                  1.4Ghz                2GB      1.0GB
Computer4       2GHz                  1.3Ghz                2GB      1.2GB
Computer5       2GHz                  1.2Ghz                2GB      1.4GB
.
.
.
Computern       2GHz                  1.3Ghz                2GB      1.4GB
```

Since, all systems RAM and Processing power are free for almost all time. I want to utilized the unused resources. My aim is to club remaining 0.8GHz processing power of Computer1, 1.0GHz of Computer 2, ... , and 0.7GHz of Computern into ONE. If this possible then, this combined/united unused processing power can be made to do some other useful tasks. Same goes for RAM also.

Is there any way to do so ?

(Please feel free to ask queries if the question is unclear.)